# Capturing Errors in Flexigrid Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, jquery, flexigrid

I'm creating a webApp in which I show some table data using jQuery and the [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) plugin. In the ideal scenario everything goes ok but I when I return a server-side exception or a validation error on a Flexigrid's ajax request, it does nothing but keep the loading icon and the 'Processing, please wait' message.

Right now you can see this behavior in its [sample page](http://flexigrid.info/sample.html), in which the server returns a 404 error but the flexigrid appears like its still loading but never shows any error.

Is there any event I could capture and handle Flexigrid's ajax request errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#flex').flexigrid({
  onError: function(data){
       // do stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how could I miss its declaration at the beginning of the flexigrid's code.